# Webpack raw loader from from public path?

Tags: node.js, webpack, vue.js, vue-component, raw-loader

I am currently using the webpack raw loader to load a file like so:

```
import svg from '!!raw-loader!./../../public/images/svg/project/flag.svg';
```

I am using this with Vue.js and I would like to create a method, mixer or plugin to resolve automatically to my public path.

How can I make the raw loader start from the root of my project instead of building up a relative path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here:

http://moduscreate.com/es6-es2015-import-no-relative-path-webpack/

Added this to my webpack config, which now works fine:

```
resolve: {
    modules: [
        path.resolve('./'),
        path.resolve('./node_modules')
    ]
}
```